# htaccess on heroku for django app

Tags: django, .htaccess, heroku

The title pretty much sums up my question.  I would like to to password protect some files in my django app that lives on heroku.
If I can't use htaccess does anyone have suggestions on what else I could use?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather not use anything django specific because I have a test, production and demo server to deal with

Comment: Why not use `SITE_ID` and the sites framework to differentiate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @mipadi said, you can't use htaccess on Heroku, but you can create a middleware for that:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


def basic_challenge(realm=None):
    if realm is None:
        realm = getattr(settings, 'WWW_AUTHENTICATION_REALM', _('Restricted Access'))
    # TODO: Make a nice template for a 401 message?
    response =  HttpResponse(_('Authorization Required'), mimetype="text/plain")
    response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="%s"' % (realm)
    response.status_code = 401
    return response

def basic_authenticate(authentication):
    # Taken from paste.auth
    (authmeth, auth) = authentication.split(' ',1)
    if 'basic' != authmeth.lower():
        return None
    auth = auth.strip().decode('base64')
    username, password = auth.split(':',1)
    AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME = getattr(settings, 'BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME')
    AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD = getattr(settings, 'BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD')
    return username == AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME and password == AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD

class BasicAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not getattr(settings, 'BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION', False):
            return
        if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in request.META:
            return basic_challenge()
        authenticated = basic_authenticate(request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
        if authenticated:
            return
        return basic_challenge()
```

Then you need to define in `settings.py`:

```
BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME = "your user"
BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD = "your pass"
BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION = True
```

Comment: This worked great.  How can I edit this so it only works for specific urls?

Comment: I actually figured this out by using request.META['PATH_INFO'] to check the url and return if I don't want that url password protected

Comment: If you receive the error `TypeError: object() takes no parameters` when using this example, you're probably using Django 1.10 or later which requires the addition of `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin` or the old-style middleware to be upgraded. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-middleware.

Comment: Great answer! Note: Python 3 users will get an `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'̀. They'll need to import the `base64` module and change `auth.strip().decode('base64')` to `base64.b64decode(b).decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to use `.htaccess` files on heroku with the cedar stack.

1. `Procfile` needs to specify a script for the web nodes:

   ```
   web:    sh www/conf/web-boot.sh
   ```
2. The `conf/web-boot.sh` slipstreams the include of a apache configuration file, e.g.:
3. A `conf/httpd/default.conf` then can allow override, as you know it from apache.

You can then just use `.htaccess` files. The whole process is documented in detail in my blog post [**PHP on Heroku again**](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/php-on-heroku-again/) of which one part is about the apache configuration. The step in 2. including your own httpd configuration basically is:

```
sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen '$PORT'/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/^DocumentRoot/# DocumentRoot/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/^ServerLimit 1/ServerLimit 8/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i 's/^MaxClients 1/MaxClients 8/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf

for var in `env|cut -f1 -d=`; do
  echo "PassEnv $var" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf;
done
echo "Include /app/www/conf/httpd/*.conf" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
touch /app/apache/logs/error_log
touch /app/apache/logs/access_log
tail -F /app/apache/logs/error_log &
tail -F /app/apache/logs/access_log &
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/app/www
echo "Launching apache"
exec /app/apache/bin/httpd -DNO_DETACH
```

I hope this is helpful. I used this for .htaccess and for changing the webroot.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use .htaccess, because Heroku apps aren't served with Apache. You can use [Django authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/), though.

Or you can serve the files from another server that *is* using Apache.

Comment: Who says Heroku apps aren't served with Apache? I have a apache configuration that works fine. To which stack does your answer belong to? I have no problems to use .htaccess files on cedar, the base setup is [documented on my blog](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/php-on-heroku-again/) in case that's interesting.

Comment: @hakre: Most stacks use nginx. Maybe the PHP buildpack does something differently.

Comment: Okay, that might probably be the case. I know what you can create your own buildback, so specifying the webserver software even.