# How to configure Google Domains + Heroku w a Naked Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, dns, google-domain-api

I have a domain loading in a web browser using Heroku and Google Domains. Right now the domain loads with a www: http://www. XXX .com.

If I enter the URL w/o the WWW like http:// XXX .com I get the following error in Chrome: "XXX.com’s server DNS address could not be found"

What do I need to do so that the following happens:

1. This loads - http:// mydomain.com
2. http://www. mydomain.com redirects to http:// mydomain.com

Thank you

Comment: @michaelsnowden, I think it is possible to achieve. Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Jeremie I'll try it soon and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should:

1/ Set your heroku domain to be http://example.com. All the info are in the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

Heroku should serve your site using http://example.com.

2/ You need to redirect in Google Domains your http://www.example.com to http://example.com. To do this, you need to set web forwarding in the Google Domain console under the website tab. The [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141) is straight forward.

Any http://www.example.com request should be forwarded to http://example.com.

**UPDATE**

Due to your needs, I am wondering if the best is not to disable the naked to www redirection, have both domain points to your heroku instance and get a SSL certificate for them (using let's encrypt makes things easy).

Here is a [tutorial](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/01/12/lets-encrypt-with-a-rails-app-on-heroku).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I can't do that using web forwarding because the only options are to "Redirect both example.com and www.example.com to an existing website", and if I enter "https://example.com", then it says "You can't forward a website to itself!".

Comment: @michaelsnowden I edited my answer for another method.

Comment: I don't think I can use htaccess on Heroku (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400862/2770572). Also, example.com doesn't point to my Heroku instance--example.com redirects to www.example.com, which points to my Heroku instance.

Comment: I have exactly two settings in Google Domains. 1) A "Synthetic Record" which is a "subdomain forward" from the subdomain "example.com" to "https://www.example.com" via a "temporary redirect (302)" without "path forwarding". 2) A "custom resource record" which is of type "CNAME" with the name "www" and the data "www.example.com.herokudns.com". I need to use "www.example.com.herokudns.com" instead of "example.herokuapp.com" in order for their SSL to work.

Comment: So, the www domain works, and that's the expected behaviour. But is the naked domain redirecting to www or to self? You wrote 'the subdomain "example.com" to "example.com";'.

Comment: Unfortunately, the stackoverflow auto-formatting really screwed me up. It should read 1) A "Synthetic Record" which is a "subdomain forward" from the subdomain `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` via a "temporary redirect (302)" without "path forwarding".

Comment: I see! I thought so. This sounds good, but you are saying that the naked domain doesn't work? What happen when you try to curl the domain ? Do you get a 302?

Comment: Yeah I get a 302 curling `example.com` which redirects to `https://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 22):

It's advisable to make the `www` subdomain the default here, such that the root/naked domain redirects to `www`. This is in line with [Heroku recommendations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains), which states:

> For maximum scalability and resiliency applications should avoid using
>   DNS A-records and instead use a DNS provider that supports CNAME
>   functionality at the apex, or use sub-domains exclusively

You can achieve this with Google Domains Synthetic Records:

- Go to the Synthetic Records section
- Select Subdomain forward
- Enter `@` for subdomain, and `www.xyz.com` for destination

Comment: But OP wants the URL in the browser to appear as http:// mydomain.com. Are you saying this isn't possible/recommended?

Comment: @michaelsnowden: for scalability and resiliency, it isn't recommended unless your DNS provider supports CNAME at the apex (or ALIAS or ANAME). You can see that Google Domains doesn't: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251147 . Heroku does list the ones which do: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains

Comment: That's disappointing. I feel like the root domains look a lot better, but I already purchased a google domain. Thanks for the authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use some 3rd party DNS provider like Cloudflare to do this. I just went through this same process. App hosted on Heroku with a domain purchased from Google. Signed up for a free account with Cloudflare and was up and running in about an hour following this guide: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698

Things I did:

- Delete DNS rules I had tried adding earlier to Google under "Custom resource records"
- Have just one domain added in Heroku for the root: "myapp.com" (**not** "www.myapp.com", **not** "*.myapp.com") which gave me a DNS address like "blah-blah-12345-herokudns.com"
- In Cloudflare add two CNAME records on the DNS page:

  1. CNAME "myapp.com" blah-blah-12345-herokudns.com
  2. CNAME "www" blah-blah-12345-herokudns.com
- Copy over custom DNS nameservers into Google from Cloudflare

After that now I can go to `myapp.com` and it just works. Super stoked because I really didn't want `www.myapp.com`.

One cool thing is I had already set up an GSuite account for the domain and when I signed up for Cloudflare it imported all the DNS rules from Google, including the MX records for email so it worked seamlessly.

Comment: Does it take time for this to work? I've followed exactly these steps and it doesn't work :(

Comment: IIRC it worked almost immediately. I'd either check all these things to make sure they're correct (it's definitely confusing) otherwise maybe they changed how it works since I posted this :/

Answer (score 0):

After some research, to set up a redirect from a naked domain (e.g., example.com) to a www subdomain (e.g., [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) using Heroku and Google Domains, you can use a third-party domain host provider like Cloudflare. Cloudflare has a free tier and is easy to use for configuring an HTTP to HTTPS redirect. It is also secure and fast.

Found this link useful on how to do that: https://www.derricksherrill.com/tutorial/web-dev/google-domains-cloudflare/